# Cost Breakdown for Curiosity Development

Tags: curiosity, cost

Is there a breakdown of the 2.5 Billion USD cost for Curiosity?
I am particularly interested in the cost of the software development of the rover.

Comment: [Topic from Programmers section, you might find it interesting](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159637/what-is-the-mars-curiosity-rovers-software-built-in) Also... [Why Curiosity Cost $2.5 Billion](http://www.investopedia.com/financial-edge/0912/why-curiosity-cost-2.5-billion.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I found this breakdown on [another website](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120830044334AAt9apf):

Source: [NASA's FY2010 budget](http://www.nasa.gov/pdf/345951main_4_Planetary_Science_FY%202010_UPDATED_final.pdf).

Spacecraft \$ 943.3 million
Payloads \$ 124.3 million
Systems I&T \$ 92.0 million
Launch Vehicle/Services \$ 215.1 million
Ground Systems \$ 77.7 million
Science/Technology \$ 16.9 million
Other direct project cost \$ 161.7 million
Total development cost $ 1.631 billion in 2009 dollars.

I haven't found a separate line item for software development, so that's part of the \$ 1067M for the R&D, design and construction of the spacecraft + payloads. 
Even the [600-page detailed budget](http://www.nasa.gov/news/budget/FY2010.html) doesn't list software development separately.

Answer (score 2):

This [video on MSL flight software development](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jVt5vb68xA) has some information on the workforce for software development and software testing, from which you can derive some rough cost numbers.