# Cost per pound to Mars?

Tags: mars

I was wondering if anyone knew a rough, ball park estimate of the cost per pound to send something to Mars. I know it can vary depending on mission, but I'm having trouble on finding an estimate. Thanks,

Comment: Here's an estimate to get you started (I think the question is on topic by the way?) http://www.space.com/17556-giant-nasa-rocket-space-launch-cost.html

Comment: This is very broad and open to opinion. There was a Mars One question that was more focused. http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/is-there-an-independent-cost-estimate-of-the-mars-one-proposal?rq=1

Comment: There are many possible mission designs for getting to Mars. Which you choose has a big impact on price. Also there is only a small sample size of items soft-landed on the Martian surface to go on. If you looked into the costs of each, then you'd have a starting point, but future missions could be very different. See [Cost Breakdown for Curiosity Development](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/8815/4660)

Comment: To Mars surface or orbit ?

Comment: Are you asking about rocket costs; i.e. "How much would it cost to send a pound of material to Mars" ?

Comment: Maybe some key facts can help you out. 1 - all missions to Mars have had a propulsion system custom designed and fabricated just for that mission, to get the ship from escape velocity from Earth to Mars orbit 2- same goes for the stage that got them through the Martian atmosphere and safely landed, and those systems are widely different depending on the size and mass of what you want to land 3 - only NASA has successfully landed anything on Mars, and they are able to do that because of a vast amount of people and infrastructure to do such things, so let's call that priceless.